# Dynamic scaling for statefulset best practices

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, kubernetes, autoscaling, horizontal-scaling

#### Background

I have app running in kubernetes cluster using sharded mongodb and elasticsearch statefulsets. I setup horizontal pod autoscalers for deployment components in my app and everything works well.

#### Problems

Problems arise when the traffic goes up. My server deployment scales out just fine, but mongodb shards and elasticsearch nodes cannot handle this much traffic and throttle overall response time.

Simple solution is to configure those statefulset with more shards, more replicas. What bugs me is that traffic spike happens like 3-4 hours a day, thus it's kinda wasteful to let all those boys sitting idly for the rest of the day.

I did some research and looks like database in general is not supposed to scale out/in dynamically as it will consume a lot of network and disk io just to do replication between them. Also there is potential of data loss and inconsistency during scaling up, scaling down.

#### Questions

If possible, what is proper way to handle dynamic scaling in mongodb, elasticsearch... and database in general?
If not, what can I do to save some cents off my cloud bill as we only need the maximum power from database pods for a short period per day.

Comment: I would imagine the MongoDB/Elasticsearch Operators have mechanisms for scaling out the Statefulsets. I don't have experience with these but I would look at the Custom Resources supported by those Operators to determine what functionality they offer.

Answer (score 1):

You should read about Kubernetes autoscaling - [HPA](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/).

> The Horizontal Pod Autoscaler automatically scales the number of pods in a replication controller, deployment, replica set or stateful set based on observed CPU utilization (or, with custom metrics support, on some other application-provided metrics). Note that Horizontal Pod Autoscaling does not apply to objects that can't be scaled, for example, DaemonSets.
>
> The Horizontal Pod Autoscaler is implemented as a Kubernetes API resource and a controller. The resource determines the behavior of the controller. The controller periodically adjusts the number of replicas in a replication controller or deployment to match the observed average CPU utilization to the target specified by user.

With HPA you should have to also take care about the volume mounting and data latency.

---

As @Serge mentioned in comments, I would  suggest to check the native scaling cluster option provided by the MongoDB and Elasticsearch itself.

Take a look at

- MongoDB operator [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/kubernetes-operator/master/tutorial/install-k8s-operator/)
- Elasticsearch operator [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/blog/introducing-elastic-cloud-on-kubernetes-the-elasticsearch-operator-and-beyond)
- Elasticsearch future release [autoscaling](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/xpack-autoscaling.html)

I am not very familiar with MongoDB and Elasticsearch with Kubernetes, but maybe those tutorials help you:

- https://medium.com/faun/scaling-mongodb-on-kubernetes-32e446c16b82
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J7h0F34iBx0
- https://kubernetes.io/blog/2017/01/running-mongodb-on-kubernetes-with-statefulsets/
- https://sematext.com/blog/elasticsearch-operator-on-kubernetes/#toc-what-is-the-elasticsearch-operator-1

---

If you use [helm](https://helm.sh/) take a look at banzaicloud [Horizontal Pod Autoscaler operator](https://github.com/banzaicloud/hpa-operator)

> You may not want nor can edit a Helm chart just to add an autoscaling feature. Nearly all charts supports custom annotations so we believe that it would be a good idea to be able to setup autoscaling just by adding some simple annotations to your deployment.
>
> We have open sourced a Horizontal Pod Autoscaler operator. This operator watches for your Deployment or StatefulSet and automatically creates an HorizontalPodAutoscaler resource, should you provide the correct autoscale annotations.

---

Hope you find this useful.